# Cannot run .net ef even though tooling installed

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to get ef core working within xamrian and I am having a few issues with the dotnet command not running. I have added the tools as per another so but that did not work.

This is my first migration and my conneciton stirng is set in the application.json of

> "ConnectionStrings": {
>       "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DEVELOPER\SAGESQL2014;Initial
>   Catalog=CallManagment;Integrated
>   Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"   } }

This is the error I am getting thanks for the help.

> dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration dotnet : No executable found
>   matching command "dotnet-ef" At line:1 char:1
>   + dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No executable f...and "dotnet-ef":String) [], RemoteExcept     ion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandErro

This is my project file at present

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System">
      <HintPath>System</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

EDIT 2 TO show assembles added.

[image]

**Edit 3**

To Show changes made from below suggestion still not working.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />

  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System">
      <HintPath>System</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714468/net-entity-framework-core/49715930#49715930)

Comment: Still not working still same result

Comment: @Thangadurai please see above image added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to run inside Package Manager Console? If so you'll need to `cd` to the project directory. Also, if you're inside PMC, why aren't you using the [EF Core PMC tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell)?

Comment: This was indead the answers had no idea you had to do this would have assumed you would be in the directory of the startup project automatically weird one

Comment: having weird issue with datanoations now for some reaosn